# How I can make space on left 12 px white and remove 12px from content in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a page that has a 12px margin from left. I want to set the background grey for 12px (no matter for this).

After setting the 12px left margin on left I want to give all other screensize to container how I can gave it.

see at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7vzSQ/

What I want is : suppose in future if I gave my page a background and the 12px left is white margin then does anyone know a trick so that .container will got all screensize (except 12px margin I set through margin-left)

```
<div class="container">

    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <div class="logo">
                test
            </div>
        </hgroup>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="logo">

        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</div>
```

someone check http://jsfiddle.net/7vzSQ/7/embedded/result/ I have updated three background but don't know why it's not appear in page.

My main purpose for doing this is I can gave all width (100% -12px) to .container. If I gave 100% it's will not work. I tried calc feature of css3 not worked. I try calc(100%+ 12px) worked but calc(100% - 12px) not working (with minus)  sign.

Do anyone have guess for get it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <style>
body{margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
#cover
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;

    padding: 0px 0px 0px 12px;
    margin:0px;
}
#inner{width:100%; height: 200px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: #bababa; }

</style>



<div id="cover">  
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

It may help you.

Comment: well thanks for your help, but it's not working. can you tried it on http://pastehtml.com/view/coq9fohha.html.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be supercool, you use [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc):

```
#container{
  margin-left:12px;
  width: 100%;              /* fallback for non-supporters, produces scrollbar */
  width:    -moz-calc(100% -12px); 
  width: -webkit-calc(100% -12px);
  width:         calc(100% -12px); 
}
```

This however disqualifies all IE-users until version 8 and those poor Opera guys:-D (see the MDN-Compat list or **[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)**).

If you want to be very oldschool, you use absolute positioning (running into overflow issues)

```
#container{
    position:absolute;
    left:12px;right:0;
}
```

and a bit less oldschool you use a wrapper-element:

```
#outerwrapper{
     padding-left:12px;
}
#container{
     width:100%;
}
```

with the markup:

```
<div id="outerwrapper">
   <div id="container">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not work in Chrome dev and Fx21 even. it's worked with + sign but not minus - sign.

Comment: I don't know why jsfiddle not take my changes. @Christoph Thanks for help me. take a look http://pastehtml.com/view/coq9fohha.html

Comment: I don't know how to alter your example on pastbin. Mind explaining it to me? Or you can alter the jsfiddle and click "update" next to the "run" button and give me the new url.

Answer (score 0):

Rupali & Christoph, thanks you both to help me in this issue. I finally got a solution for my issue.

```
<div class="topline">

</div>
    <div class="bgs">
        <div class="bg1 bg"></div>
        <div class="bg2 bg"></div>
        <div class="bg3 bg"></div>
    </div>
<div class="container">

    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Blah blah</h1>
                <div class="desc">
                lorem ipsum dollar sit amet
                </div>
            </div>
        </hgroup>
    </header>
    <div class="content">

    </div>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</div>


.bgs {
  float: left;
}
.bgs .bg {
  width: 9px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.bgs .bg1 {
  background: #0068B3;
}
.bgs .bg2 {
  background: #65B561;
}
.bgs .bg3 {
  background: #F99D32;
}
.container {
  margin-left: 50px;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

This will make it work for me.

Comment: Fine, if it helped you, feel free to accept Rupali's or my answer;)